# Partial correlation with continuous and categorical variables (SPSS)

Tags: spss, partial-correlation, controlling-for-a-variable

I have results of 7 neuropsychological tests, and I am studying the convergent/divergent validity of one of these tests. These are the continuous variables.

I also have background variables:

- gender (1/2)
- education (1-5)
- age (years)

I want to know the correlations between the neuropsychological tests, controlling for the background variables. Gender is categorical, education is ordinal and age is continuous.

In SPSS, partial correlation variables should all be continuous. How can I see the 'pure' adjusted correlations between the tests, with all the background variables controlled for simultaneously?

I have a vague idea that I might have to use the GLM menu (instead of Correlate) to do this, but I'm not sure about it. I ran ANCOVA (regression -> linear) with one particular neuropsychological test result I was interested in as the dependent, and with gender and age as independents. Neither gender nor age were significant in the resulting Coefficients table.